# jmeter spring boot actuator jmx monitor

Tags: spring-boot, jmeter, jmx, spring-boot-actuator

Has anybody got a JMeter perf mon or JMXMon graphs or some kind of monitor graph to work with Spring Boot Actuator using JSON/HTML ports?

Our environment is precluded from accessing native RMI JMX ports remotely.

Can we use JMETER somehow to access the Spring Boot Actuator HTTP endpoints for JMX data?
Using maybe something like:

```
http:localhost:9001/jolokia/read/java.lang:type=Memory/HeapMemoryUsage
```

Getting JSON response like:

```
{"request":{"mbean":"java.lang:type=Memory","attribute":"HeapMemoryUsage","type":"read"},"value":{"init":398458880,"committed":653262848,"max":5648678912,"used":75715736},"timestamp":1481057021,"status":200}
```

http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2011/03/jolokia-highcharts-jmx-for-human-beings.html

Answer (score 4):

created a Throughput Controller added a Sampler to the `/jolokia/read/java.lang:type=Memory/HeapMemoryUsage`

add some regex magic voodoo soup: `"used":(\d+)`
Wow, the Data Extractor (a [jmeter plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PageDataExtractor/)), is not running every iteration, but it seems to be running pretty frequent.  That's another issue for another Stack Overflow posting.
Happy for now. Hope this helps somebody.
[image]

Comment: what Sampler did you add to the Throughput Controller?

Comment: just as a small reference - this jmeter-plugin https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PageDataExtractor/ is needed